# IE showing JBoss Welcome Page at localhost:8080 when JBoss is not running

Tags: internet-explorer, jboss

I have this weird issue happening on my PC and cannot figure out why it is happening. Hopefully someone can help me out.

My PC's operating system is Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

On my PC there is no JBoss running.

- When I open IE and go to http://localhost:8080/ address, JBoss Welcome Page shows up.

[image]

- When I open Chrome and go to http://localhost:8080/ address, JBoss Welcome Page does not show up and instead I get this message:

> This webpage is not available 
>   ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

- When I open Firefox and go to http://localhost:8080/ address, JBoss Welcome Page does not show up and instead I get this message:

> Unable to connect 
>   Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8080.
>   ...

- When I open Opera and go to http://localhost:8080/ address, JBoss Welcome Page does not show up and instead I get this message:

> This webpage is not available 
>   Opera's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.
>   ...

So why IE is showing JBoss Welcome Page when JBoss is not running?

Why IE is not acting the same way as other browsers in this case?

### UPDATE:

In IE on the JBoss Welcome Page, when I click on any JBoss Management link (Tomcat status, JMX Console or JBoss Web Console) then I get this error message:

> This page can’t be displayed
>  Make sure the web address
>   http://localhost:8080 is correct
>  ...

So IE recognize that JBoss is not running but why show the JBoss Welcome Page? Bizarre.

Thanks

Comment: Likely cached. In I.E hold CTRL and press F5, or CTRL+Refresh icon.

Comment: @Darren tried your solution but still the same issue